# Is there a difference between "Build" and CI?

Tags: configuration, build, build-process, continuous-integration, build-automation

I've recently been assigned the task of being responsible for defining new processes and methodologies within my team, with regards to correct development processes.

I'd like to know if there is any significant difference between the term Build and the term CI.

I know that usually CI is the process of building your project after each commit to have better indication on the commit level for each developer.

Is there any difference in the build or in the process that is performed when doing CI and when running a normal "Build" ? (e.g. Daily build of the project)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The build process is everything that goes into building the software (getting the source code, compiling it, packaging it, automated tests etc...).

CI is the triggering of a build on commit.

A "daily build" is a time trigger for the build.

Comment: So essentially the same process (compile, unit tests, doc, etc) will run on both?

Answer (score 0):

Continuous Integration contains a Build step and much more - it may run automated tests, email developers when their commits caused a build failure, automatic deployment. So I guess the difference is in the number of concepts and steps involved in each one of them.